# How to download magnet link with C#?

Tags: c#, torrent

Im working on a project which i need to download a magnet link from torrent websites. For example i give the magnet link to a text box and it downloads the content of that magnet link in the specified folder.

I wanted to use monotorrent but it was very complicated and it actually didnt work and it just throw some errors and one of them was "URI prefix is not recognized" and didnt know how to solve it.

and again, all i want to do is to download the magnet link and maybe show the progress with the progress bar

How can I implement such a program with C#?

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote for monotorrent in your answer? We might be able to help you correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Process.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) will open the magnet URL with the default application set for handling them. It won't open in your application, but then you'd be writing a torrent application (which is not the easiest task...):

```
string magnetUrl = "magnet:?xt=urn:sha1: ..."
Process.Start(magnetUrl);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be programmaticaly downloading torrent file and then run a program with parameter which is the path to torrent file. For example you could use cygwin with rtorrent (command-line torrent client)

Comment: is it possible to show me an example of what you said?